# How do I retrieve a value of a field in a queryset object

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and have the following model:

```
class MainFile(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # docfile = models.FileField(verbose_name= 'Enter you file', null=True)
    file_id = models.UUIDField(max_length=38, primary_key=True, default=1)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    file_suffix = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    file_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

So I want to filter a row of the table using file_id, and having that row, access the file_suffix. Currently I've found the following way but it's tricky:

```
obj = MainFile.objects.filter(file_id = 'e3e978a3-0375-4bb9-85a2-5175e2ec097d')
suffix = [i.file_suffix for i in obj]
```

I tried many ways but no luck except the above but I know that's not the correct way. How can I get the file_suffix after creating the obj using file_id as filter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `get` instead of `filter`

```
obj = MainFile.objects.get(file_id='e3e978a3-0375-4bb9-85a2-5175e2ec097d')
obj.file_suffix
```

Use `get` when your queryset will fetch at most 1 row back from the database. In this case, since `file_id` is marked as the primary key, you can be certain that it is unique.

Comment: The `get "trick"` helped me a lot! I was using `filter` and then I was receiving an array with one element. Ty

Answer (score 7):

You can do this as a one-liner with simply:

```
MainFile.objects.values_list('file_suffix', flat=True).get(file_id='e3e978a3-0375-4bb9-85a2-5175e2ec097d')
```

the [`values_list` queryset method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) retrieves only the column data that you need from the database. The [`get` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get) then returns the single match to your filter.